# Child View Controller don't appear on device

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios-simulator, uitabbar, childviewcontroller

I'v developed custom  `UITabbarController` with my own tabbar layout. I've got a set of `UIViewController`, that i instantiate from stroryboard like this :

```
class func instantiateMainViewControllers () -> Array<UIViewController>
{
    var controllersArray = Array<UIViewController>()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let feedVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BL_UIConst.kFeedControllerIdentifier)


    controllersArray.append(feedVC)

    let exploreVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BL_UIConst.kExploreControllerIdentifier)
    controllersArray.append(exploreVC)

    let cameraVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BL_UIConst.kCameraControllerIdentifier)
    controllersArray.append(cameraVC)

    let chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BL_UIConst.kChatControllerIdentifier)
    controllersArray.append(chatVC)

    let profileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(BL_UIConst.kProfileControllerIdentifier)
    controllersArray.append(profileVC)

    return controllersArray
}
```

And than assign to view controllers array of my custom `UITabbarController`. Switching between controllers works as follows ( custom tabbar controller has presentationView `UIView` on it to display child controller ) :

```
private func displayViewController ( atIndex index : Int ) -> Void
{
    let controller = viewControllersArray[index]

    if ( presentationView.subviews.count > 0 )
    {
        let presentedView = presentationView.subviews[0]

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < viewControllersArray.count ; i++ )
        {
            let localController = viewControllersArray[i]

            if ( localController.view == presentedView )
            {
                localController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
                localController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                localController.removeFromParentViewController()

                break
            }
        }
    }

   self.addChildViewController(controller)
   controller.view.bounds = self.presentationView.bounds
   controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, presentationView.frame.size.width, presentationView.frame.size.height - 10)
   presentationView.addSubview(controller.view)
}
```

And i make initial setup of controllers array ( selecting first one and calling displayViewController procedure ) at `viewDidAppear` function. First controller is a table view.

Than a very magic thing happens. On simulator ( iPhone 6s, iOS 9.2 - on the screenshot there is a small autolayout issue - tabbar has still static 320.0 size  and iPhone 5s, iOS 9.2 ) -

[image]

***BUT***

On device ( iPhone 5, iOS 9.2 ) i've got this on the screen ( even tab bar is in its initial state - every segment is selected ) and nothing on the screen -

[image]

I've debug every frame of child view controllers, printed frames of subviews - everything is correct. What can cause this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm managing tab bar in following way. It belongs to main Tab bar view controller. And that controller has the following configuration method -

```
private func setUpTabBar ( forSelectedActionSignContainer imageView : UIImageView ) -> Void
{
    var viewControllerIndex = 0

    if ( imageView == feedSign )
    {
        feedSign.hidden = false
        exploreSign.hidden = true
        cameraSign.hidden = true
        chatSign.hidden = true
        profileSign.hidden = true
        viewControllerIndex = 0
    }
    if ( imageView == exploreSign )
    {
        feedSign.hidden = true
        exploreSign.hidden = false
        cameraSign.hidden = true
        chatSign.hidden = true
        profileSign.hidden = true
        viewControllerIndex = 1
    }
    if ( imageView == cameraSign )
    {
        feedSign.hidden = true
        exploreSign.hidden = true
        cameraSign.hidden = false
        chatSign.hidden = true
        profileSign.hidden = true
        viewControllerIndex = 2
    }
    if ( imageView == chatSign )
    {
        feedSign.hidden = true
        exploreSign.hidden = true
        cameraSign.hidden = true
        chatSign.hidden = false
        profileSign.hidden = true
        viewControllerIndex = 3
    }
    if ( imageView == profileSign )
    {
        feedSign.hidden = true
        exploreSign.hidden = true
        cameraSign.hidden = true
        chatSign.hidden = true
        profileSign.hidden = false
        viewControllerIndex = 4
    }

   displayViewController(atIndex: viewControllerIndex)
}
```

Each tab in bar has it's own action and each green line at bottom has it's outlet :

```
    @IBAction func feedControllerSelected()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: feedSign)
}

@IBAction func exploreControllerSelected()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: exploreSign)
}

@IBAction func cameraControllerSelected()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: cameraSign)
}

@IBAction func chatControllerSelected()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: chatSign)
}


@IBAction func profileControllerSelected()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: profileSign)
}

private func initialSetUp()
{
    setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: feedSign)
}
```

And in `viewDidAppear` of tabbar controller i make initial configuration by calling `setUpTabBar(forSelectedActionSignContainer: feedSign)`. So child controllers don't manage anything, line in the original `UITabbarController`

**EDIT 2**

All this happens on device, when i adding `UITableView` to child view controller. Without it - everything works. It seems like some exception rises on device, but it doesn't propagate to xcode via wire somehow.

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't tell anything about the issue, it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @FahriAzimov - that's all buisness logic. After some investigation - i found that when i modify frame of new view controller without adding it as a subview or child view controller - tabbar rolls to initial state with all tabs selected!

Comment: I see, then you are setting selected images to tabbar on `viewDidLoad` of view controllers. That's the main issue here, when you modify the frame of the view controller which did not load it's view previously, it forces `viewDidLoad` to be called, that's where all the tabs getting selected.

Comment: @FahriAzimov - not exactly. See edits of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after 4 hours of investigation i found the following :

1. My issue reproduces only if start view controller contains table view
2. It doesn't reproduce, if table view contains 0 rows
3. It still reproduces with default `UITabbarController`
4. In my `UITableViewCell`, surely a custom one, i've got horizontal scroller - `HorizontalTableView` form GitHub.
5. After removing it, everything works like a charm.

**SUMMARY**

1. This issue definitely causes by some internal UIKit exception, that doesn't raise it properly
2. It reproduces **only** on real devices. In simulator there's no such problem
3. How could Apple do this in UIKit?! Hate em all! Cook, apple, xcode!

Thanks everyone!